# Yocto- how to get a link map for the kernel?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'd like to modify my Bitbake .bbappend file (for linux-imx) to have it generate a linker map file. I've tried things like the following with no success (though they do seem to work correctly for non-kernel recipes):

```
LDFLAGS += "-Map mymap.map"
LDFLAGS += "-Map=mymap.map"
LDFLAGS_append = " -Map mymap.map"
```

The end goal is to verify whether or not the on-chip RAM (which is at a fixed address) is being used or not.

Comment: Isn't `system.map` created automatically in your linux-imx workbuild?

Comment: Yes, but I have the impression that is tailored for the kernel's use and I'm not sure how complete it is (since it does not look like the usual ld link map).